# Python console not loading with QGIS1.7-Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS lucid,

Tags: qgis

Any tips on how to get the Python console working on Q-GIS (Quantum GIS)? (Its not working from the software's menu.)

System:

- Python 2.6.5
- QGIS1.7 OS
- Linux: Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS lucid

Error message from python running in the Terminal window:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) 
    [GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> from qgis.core import *
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v7.0 to v7.1 but the qgis.core module requires API v6.0
    >>>
```

Answer (score 1):

[This answer from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983607/what-should-i-do-to-get-pyqt4-working) worked for me:

Steps:

1. $apt-get remove qgis
2. $apt-get update
3. $apt-get upgrade pyqt* python-qt4
4. $apt-get install qgis